# Is is possible to store a reference to an object method?

Tags: php

Assume this class code:

```
class Foo {
    function method() {
        echo 'works';
    }
}
```

Is there any way to store a reference to the `method` method of a `Foo` instance?

I'm just experimenting and fiddling around, my goal is checking whether PHP allows to call `$FooInstance->method()` without writing `$FooInstance->` every time. I know I could write a function wrapper for this, but I'm more interested in getting a reference to the instance method.

For example, this pseudo-code would theoretically store `$foo->method` in the `$method` variable:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$method = $foo->method; //Undefined property: Foo::$method 
$method();
```

Apparently, as `method` is a method and I'm not calling it with `()` the interpreter thinks I'm looking for a property thus this doesn't work.

I've read through [Returning References](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php) but the examples only show how to return references to variables, not methods.

Therefore, I've adapted my code to store an anonymous function in a variable and return it:

```
class Foo {
    function &method() {
        $fn = function() {
            echo 'works';
        };
        return $fn;
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$method = &$foo->method();
$method();
```

This works, but is rather ugly. Also, there's no neat way to call it a single time, as this seems to require storing the returned function in a variable prior to calling it: `$foo->method()();` and `($foo->method())();` are syntax errors.

Also, I've tried returning the anonymous function directly without storing it in a variable, but then I get the following notice:

> **Notice**: Only variable references should be returned by reference

Does this mean that returning/storing a reference to a class instance method is impossible/discouraged or am I overlooking something?

---

**Update:** I don't mind adding a getter if necessary, the goal is just getting a reference to the method. I've even tried:

```
class Foo {
    var $fn = function() {
        echo 'works';
    };
    function &method() {
        return $this->fn;
    }
}
```

But from the `unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION)` error I'd believe that PHP wisely doesn't allow properties to store functions.

I'm starting to believe that my goal isn't easily achievable without the use of ugly hacks as `eval()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is. You have to use an array, with two values: the class instance (or string of the class name if you are calling a static method) and the method name as a string. This is documented on the [Callbacks Man page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php):

> A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

Demo ([Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/AUFm14)):

```
<?php
class Something {
    public function abc() {
        echo 'called';
    }
}

$some = new Something;

$meth = array($some, 'abc');

$meth(); // 'called'
```

Note this is also works with the built-ins that require callbacks ([Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ZjgV0n)):

```
class Filter {
    public function doFilter($value) {
        return $value !== 3;
    }
}

$filter = new Filter;
$test = array(1,2,3,4,5);
var_dump(array_filter($test, array($filter, 'doFilter'))); // 'array(1,2,4,5)'
```

And for static methods -- note the `'Filter'` instead of an instance of a class as the first element in the array ([Codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/UkqTHD)):

```
class Filter {
    public static function doFilter($value) {
        return $value !== 3;
    }
}

$test = array(1,2,3,4,5);

var_dump(array_filter($test, array('Filter', 'doFilter'))); // 'array(1,2,4,5)'
// -------- or -----------
var_dump(array_filter($test, 'Filter::doFilter')); // As of PHP 5.2.3
```

Comment: I've seen `()` on a string variable, but it is the first time I see an array being called. Thanks for the Man page link as well. `=]`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I've updated to add a link to the docs page. Its with the callbacks. It's been a convention for a while, but I think it looks terribly ugly.

Comment: If you call that ugly, I hope you never have to read through my JavaScript snippets. `;)` Thanks again for the quick answer.

Comment: Yow. The ordinary way to do this in most languages would be to use a closure to eta-convert (à la the almost-PHP `$meth = function() { $some->abc() }`)

Comment: @hobbs Agreed on the yow. Calling an array (technically a hash) seems illogical to me too. I just read in the docs that 5.2.3 lets you use the more docs-like syntax to refer to static methods `call_user_func('Something::someStaticMethod')`. If only this worked with instances (like `call_user_func('$instance::someInstanceMethod')`) but I guess that would conflict with static constants.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can. PHP has a "callable" pseudo-type, which is, in fact, either just a string or an array. Several functions ([`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) comes to mind) accept a parameter of the "callback" type: in fact, they just want a function name, or an object-method pair.

That's right, strings are callable:

```
$fn = "strlen";
$fn("string"); // returns 6
```

As mentioned, it's possible to use an array as a callback, too. In that case, the first element has to be an object, and the second argument must be a method name:

```
$obj = new Foo();
$fn = array($obj, "method");
$fn(); // calls $obj->method()
```

Previously, you had to use `call_user_func` to call them, but syntax sugar in recent versions make it possible to perform the call straight on variables.

You can read more on the ["callable" documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).

Comment: Yes, I was aware of strings holding function names, but it is the first time I see the array syntax. +1 for the detailed answer, I'd accept this but @PhpMyCoder answered first.

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know it's not possible to store a reference to a method in PHP. Storing object / class name and a method name in an array works, but it's just an array without any special meaning. You can play with the array as you please, for example:

```
$ref = [new My_Class(), "x"];
// all is fine here ...
$ref();
// but this also valid, now the 'reference' points to My_Other_Class::x()
// do you expect real reference to behave like this?
$ref[0] = new My_Other_Class();
$ref();
// this is also valid syntax, but it throws fatal error
$ref[0] = 1; 
$ref();
// let's assume My_Class::y() is a protected method, this won't work outside My_Class
$ref = [new My_Class(), 'y'];
$ref();
```

- this is prone to error as you loose syntax checking due to storing the method name as string.
- you can't pass reliably a reference to a private or a protected method this way (unless you call the reference from a context that already has proper access to the method).

Personally I prefer to use lambdas:

```
$ref = function() use($my_object) { $my_object->x(); }
```

If you do this from inside `$my_object` it gets less clunky thanks to access to `$this`:

```
$ref = function() { $this->x(); }
```

- this works with protected / private methods
- syntax checking works in IDE (less bugs)
- unfortunately it's less concise