# Storing a trait function reference in an array

Tags: php

```
trait foo {

 function foo() {
   echo "bar";
 }

}

trait bar {
  use foo;

  function bar() {
   return $this->foo();
  }

}

class global {
  use test;

  public $functions = ["bar"];

  function callFunction($function) {
    call_user_func($this->functions[$function]);
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, this is the only solution I could find and it won't work unless it triggers a fatal error response with no way to suppress it using @ before any of the execution variable.  So, still kinda stuck here... can anyone help me solve this? I can only hide the display of fatal errors by using the ini_set("display_errors", 0) which still allows me to display other error types

```
How do I store the function bar() as a reference value in $functions without evoking some kind of error such as "call to undefined function bar in globals"?


Ah! Found a solution thanks to zneak here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16380836/784446 

Essentially, the solution would store both traits and trait functions by array inside a functions array and would then be referenced by combining the elements into a single array, like so:


class global {
 use test;

 public $functions = ["classes"=>["foo", "bar"], "functions"=>["foo", "bar"]];

 function callBar() {
  $traitClass = $this->functions["classes"]["bar"];
  $traitFunction = $this->functions["functions"]["bar"];
  $barTrait = array($traitClass, "$traitFunction");
  $barTrait();
 }
}
```

Special thanks to zneak for helping with this solution!

Comment: Hi! The convention here is to always keep Questions and Answers in separate sections of the page, so if you've found a solution to your own problem, you can answer your own question using the box below, and click the "Accept" mark. That way it's clearer for future readers to see what the original problem was.

Comment: Also, your code as written isn't a working example - you have `use test;` in `class global`, but no Trait with that name, and the name "global" is not allowed because it's a reserved word. When simplifying examples, always make sure to test them and confirm they give the result you're asking about, as discussed on the help page about making a [mcve].